Can you switch off an infinite regress of simulations?
I don't know where I'm going with this
I know there are objections to throwing things out to the community.
If the world is an infinite regress of simulations. Ie a matroyska doll that our world contains an infinte amount of other simulations below it , and our world is contained regressively within an infinite amount of other simulations above it.
What would happen if within one of those simulations someone switched of the simulations below it.
How does this effect an infinite regress, as now there is a base that there is nothing below it and everything above it?
What would happen if every simulation within that infinite regress were simultaneously switched off would that form a paradox between the reality of a regressive simulated universe and the result of an absence of a regressive simulated universe?
Can you therefore switch off or switch on an infinite regress of simulations?

Lets's indulge in the magical thinking. Under the very reasonnable assumption that each of those worlds run more than 1 such simulation, switching one of this off wouldn't change anything. We would still have infinite simulations beyond and above.

You can't have an infinite number of simulations, because a simulation that does zero computer operations isn't a simulation, doing one computer operation takes finite time and negentropy, infinity times finite equals infinity, and nobody has infinite negentropy to work with, let alone infinite patience.

@armand what would happen if every simulation was turned off simultaneously?

What happens when you turn off your computer, I guess.

@armand how can you switch off a machine that you cannot switch on or is on by no others means than that it is not off? That's the paradox !!

@armand Just to make it simple for you a switched of computer exists somewhere a switched off regress of simulations exists no where and that's the limitations of the English language and probably the limitations of any language you care to express!!

Your reading way more into it than it's worth. There's no paradox, you're just being confused by the semantics of a technology you don't understand. Just like when you "kill" an enemy in a game, no one dies but a subroutine of a program stops running. Same with a computer in a simulation. Install VMware on your PC and run a virtual machine, then turn it off. You'll see that reality doesn't crumble under the paradox.

@armand You sound confused I'm not confusing any of those ideas. I'm synergising the idea that if there's no God equally there's no infinite regress because if there were then that simulation needed to be switched on. God forbid if it were to be switched off!!!

Ether what we experience is rea land has no creator or it does. What we experience is a simulation with a base reality. Or we experience an infinite regress of simulations. I'm arguing that an infinite regress can only be switched on and off by God. So if I was a betting man despite a wager I would bet on God !!!!!!!!!!

Lots of emotions here... Please keep cool, ho X Ady on the exclamation marks and don't forget all this talk about simulation is nothing but baseless speculation. We have no reason to doubt the reality we are experiencing is simply real.

@armanad what about the claims that it is likely that we are in a simulation based upon our progression through the ages that an sophisticated species developed from thousands of years before we have. My argent just makes the existence of a base reality created by physics itself is one in three?
